# How many ways can the letters of MATHEMATICS be arranged if no two vowels are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to do this question from a high school textbook. The answer given is 1058400, but I can't get this answer.

Here's what I've tried so far:
There's 11!/(2^3) arrangements without any restrictions

If the two As are adjacent, then there's 10!/(2^2) arrangements (you can swap the As, but since they are repeated there's no need to)

Then you can have AE, AI, EI adjacent. In each case this is (10!*2!)/(2^3), as the two vowels can be swapped around, but the As are repeated.

Subtracting these cases from the number of arrangements without any restrictions gives 1360800, which is not the answer.

Comment: Try treating the $A$'s as distinct: $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: Try arranging `MTHMTCS` first, then pick spaces between or to the sides of the consonants to slide vowels into noting that you may only slide at most one vowel into each space.

Comment: Cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425153/how-many-arrangements-of-mathematics-are-there-in-which-each-consonant-is-adjace)

Answer (score 2):

[trancelocation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122119) did exact calculations, but he confused to give the final answer.

Of course the number of all possible arrangements without any restrictions (taking into account that A,T,M appear twice) is: $\color{blue}{\frac{11!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}}$.
But it's **irrelevant**.

### *So the answer is:*

(stating [trancelocation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122119)'s answer)

- The number of arrangements for the 7 consonants with T,M twice is: $\color{blue}{\frac{7!}{2! \cdot 2!}}$
- These consonants give rise to 8 possible places where to put at most one vowel. So, choose 4 of these 8 places: $\color{blue}{\binom{8}{4}}$
- Now, for each selection of the 4 vowels, the number of arrangements of the vowels themselves with A twice is: $\color{blue}{\frac{4!}{2!}}$

All together:
$$\color{blue}{\frac{7!}{2! \cdot 2!} \cdot \binom{8}{4} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!} = 1,058,400}$$

Comment: The second part of your answer is fine, but you should really try to write in your own words. Even though you state that this is taken from another answer, it's still frowned upon to use exact same language. If you want to state that the other answer is wrong, explain why in the comments to that answer, instead of posting a separate one. Furthermore, can you explain why "it's irrelevant"? Without explanation this is just an opinion!

Comment: In the end, the answer of $3931200$ is the correct answer to the problem of counting the number of arrangements where there is at least one vowel next to another.  The answer of $1058400$ is the correct answer to the problem of counting the number of arrangements where no vowel is next to another vowel.

Comment: @YiFan, I only wanted to comment on his answer at first, but I couldn't as I am a new user here. So the only choice was to write an answer of my own. As I said his calculations and explanations are totally right, I don't see why to rephrase them. Most of the credit goes to him, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

- All possible arrangements with A,T,M twice: $\color{blue}{\frac{11!}{2!\cdot 2! \cdot 2!}}$
- The $\color{blue}{7}$ consonants with T,M twice: $\color{blue}{\frac{7!}{2!\cdot 2!}}$
- These consonants written as list give rise to $\color{blue}{8}$ possible places where to put at most one vowel. So, choose $\color{blue}{4}$ of these places: $\color{blue}{\binom{8}{4}}$
- Now, distribute the 4 vowels into each selection of 4 of these places and note that A appears twice: $\color{blue}{}$
  $\color{blue}{\frac{4!}{2!}}$

All together:

Number of ways with no two vowels adjacent:

$$\color{blue}{\frac{7!}{2!\cdot 2!} \cdot \binom{8}{4} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!} = 1058400}$$

Number of ways with at least two vowels adjacent:

$$\color{blue}{\frac{11!}{2!\cdot 2! \cdot 2!} - \frac{7!}{2!\cdot 2!} \cdot \binom{8}{4} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!} = 3931200}$$